# error: gnome.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I would like to resolve this 'error: gnome.h: No such file or directory ' on ubuntu.

I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: gnome-config: not found
In file included from TestMDI.cpp:18:
../../../../dist/include/system_wrappers/gnome.h:3:24: error: gnome.h: No such file or directory
```

From this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=295105

I tried:
$ sudo apt-get install libgnomeui-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libgnomeui-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.

But that still does not resolve my problem.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If the program is for Gnome 1.x, you can't compile it on recent Ubuntu without code changes.

Comment: @michael This must be the problem since gnome-config was replaced by pkg-config in Gnome 2.